# Adding and removing an element in an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

There are 2 toggle buttons. If the value is `true`, then add to the `array`, otherwise remove the element.

**data:**

```
originality: []
```

**toggles:**

```
<toggle id='1' ref='toggleOriginal'> Click </toggle>
<toggle id='2' ref='toggleAnalog'> Click </toggle>
```

**methods:**

```
 if(this.$refs.toggleOriginal.isActive) {
    this.originality.push(this.$refs.toggleOriginal.id);
 } else {
    this.originality = this.originality.filter((item) => {
      return item == this.$refs.toggleOriginal.id;
   });
 }

 if(this.$refs.toggleAnalog.isActive) {
    this.originality.push(this.$refs.toggleAnalog.id);
  } else {
    this.originality = this.originality.filter((item) => {
      return item == this.$refs.toggleAnalog.id;
    });
  }
```

And the same for the second. In `isActive` I check for `true / false`.
the problem is that if two toggle is `true` and I want to convert one to `false`, then the wrong element is removed. Perhaps you should use a different functionality?

Comment: You can use a [`v-model`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/v-model.html) to link the toggle's state to a variable (for example it's ID). You can then use a [`computed value`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#computed-values) to create the `originality` array. No need to juggle their values manually.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Thanks for your replay. I dont think i can use ``v-model`` for a component. Is not it?

Comment: Of course you can use `v-model` for a component. That is a reason it exists, so you don't have to juggle the value manually between each component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove from array using filter, you should test for non-equality. Your example uses equality, and that will remove all but your item.

```
this.originality = this.originality.filter((item) => {
      return item !== this.$refs.toggleOriginal.id;
   });
```

or splice

```
const index = this.originality.indexOf(this.$refs.toggleOriginal.id)
this.originality.splice(index, 1)
```